# Request for additional information of Google Email Markup registration

Tags: google-schemas

In order to use email markup feature, we are required to request with google and follow the linked guide below
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

Besides the technical pre-requisite, We also wish to know:
1)      Can we register more than email addresses for the same company? If not,
2)      Can we change the Whitelist’s contact email address after the registration has been confirmed?

looking forward to hearing the help soon!

Answer (score 0):

@Keith Lai, yes, you can register more than one email address. Just specify which emails in the [registration form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1). If the domains are different, you will most likely have to send a sample from each domain email.

Yes, you can request to have additional email addresses whitelisted even after first initial email address has been whitelisted.